# How can I simplify $\sum_{k=0}^n a \cdot k \cdot q^k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

So I recently found out about geometrical series. However now I've got this formula:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac 1 3 k \cdot {\frac 2 3}^k$ is there also a way to simplify this?

Comment: Hint: $\sum_k k\cdot q^k = q\cdot \sum_k k\cdot q^{k-1} = q\cdot \frac d{dq}\sum_k q^k$

Comment: @jameselmore I don't understand your last step. Why is that equal and what is $d$?

Comment: Magically multiply by $(1-q)^2$ and watch the cancellations.

Comment: How did you do the geometric series formula?

Comment: @SimpleArt I don't get your first attempt, sorry. So I read about the geometric series on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) but at that time I just had a formula $\sum_{k=0}^n a \cdot q^k$ what could be simplified by the geometric series. However I can't cope with the additional $ \cdot k$. But somehow this seems like a common term for me why I think there has to be a way to simplify it similar to the geometric series. But I just can't find a way.

Comment: @fatalError Do you need finite sums or just infinite sums ?

Comment: @Peter finitie (wouldn't have put the n up there otherwise). But I feel kind of stupid right now since I have no clue what you are talking about. Maybe this formula is just too hard to solve for me.

Comment: Nah, it's just easier if you've taken calculus.

Comment: Do you know the finite sum-formula for a geometric series ? If yes, differentiate with respect to $q$ and look what happens.

Comment: Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Some_summations_involving_exponential_terms

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the desired sum.

$$S=q+2q^2+3q^3+\dots+nq^n$$

Multiply it by $(1-q)$.

$$(1-q)S=(\color{red}q+\color{blue}{2q^2}+\color{red}{3q^3}+\dots+nq^n)-(\color{blue}{q^2}+\color{red}{2q^3}+\color{blue}{3q^4}+\dots+nq^{n+1})$$

Combine like terms.  (notice the minus sign on the second set of values)

$$=\color{red}q+\color{blue}{[2-1]q^2}+\color{red}{[3-2]q^3}+\dots+[n-(n-1)]q^n-nq^{n+1}$$

$$=q(1+q+q^2+\dots+q^n)-nq^{n+1}$$

Let $G$ be the geometric sum.

$$(1-q)S=q(G-nq^n)$$

Solve for $S$.

$$S=\frac{q(G-nq^n)}{1-q}$$

---

The geometric sum:

$$G=1+q+q^2+\dots+q^n$$

Multiply it by $(1-q)$.

$$(1-q)G=(\color{red}1+\color{blue}q+\color{red}{q^2}+\dots+q^n)-(\color{blue}q+\color{red}{q^2}+\color{blue}{q^3}+\dots+q^{n+1})$$

Combine like terms.  (notice the minus sign on the second set of values)

$$=\color{red}1+\color{blue}{[1-1]q}+\color{red}{[1-1]q^2}+\dots+[1-1]q^n-q^{n+1}$$

$$(1-q)G=1-q^{n+1}$$

Solve for $G$.

$$G=\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$

Comment: I feel like a cheater now because someone posted me the right formula from Wikipedia. However I'd still like to understand it instead of just copy and and pasting it. But staring at this doesn't help me further. (*edit:* Please wait I saw that you added something maybe I get it now.)

Comment: @fatalerror try adding the $q^2$ terms, then the $q^3$ terms, then the... And see what happens.

Comment: I guess I will just go to sleep and look back at it tomorrow. I guess I'm just too tired to solve this right now... My brain is just barely working anymore...

Comment: @fatalError Same.  Got a headache to work with on my end.  Anyways, I made everything more explicit.